# Pass List<Object> from Razor View To Post Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have model View like This:

```
public class ContactHomePage
{
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public List<SqlParameter> SqlParameters { get; set; }
}
```

In Index action (that works as HTTPGet) I fill `ContactHomePage` and passed to View, and in the view, I want to pass this model to action `GetRecords`, this post action like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetRecords(JqGridRequest request, string query, List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters)
{
}
```

and my ajax post url like this:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetRecords", "Contact", new { query = Model.Query, sqlParameters = Model.SqlParameters})'
```

in running the app, `query` object that was in string mode has its data but sqlParameters with type List hasn't any value!
now my question is, how can post `List<Object>` from razor view to post action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ActionResult is type of Get, you can't sent complex data types. A solution is convert your complex object (Model.SqlParameters) to string, using **Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert**, and then parse it on ActionResult to your object. Something like this:

At razor view (**Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject**):

```
@Url.Action("MyActionResult", "MyController", new { objectStringfied = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<MyObject>()) })
```

At controller (**Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject**):

```
public virtual ActionResult MyActionResult(string objectStringfied)
{
     List<MyObject> model = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(objectStringfied);

     // ...
}
```

Comment: I got this error: Message = "Error converting value \"@FirstName\" to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter'. Path '[0]', line 1, position 13."

Comment: I think Newtonsoft hase problem in De-serialize List<SqlParameter>, I replace List<string> with List<SqlParameter>, Its work fine!

Comment: You can create a aux data type and then map it to sql parameter data type. Also, your stringfied parameter shouldn't be too long, because typically request has limit size. Otherwise change the request as a HttpPost type. Finnally... if my answer help you, don´t forget the upvote ;)